# C# How to deserialize JSON objects in an array to a list?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm new in C# and trying to retrieve all data and convert to list so I can using loop for further process. Here is the JSON data:

```json
[
    {
        "TagNumber": 0001,
        "TagName": "Tag1",
        "TimeStamp": [
            "10/27/2023 14:36:42",
            "10/27/2023 14:37:42",
            "10/27/2023 14:38:42",
            "10/27/2023 14:39:42",
            "10/27/2023 14:40:42",
            "10/27/2023 14:41:42"
        ],
        "Value": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Confidence": [
            100,
            100,
            100,
            100,
            100,
            100
        ],
        "Sequence": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is the class I Created and I used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`to convert above JSON but couldn't make it work:

```cs
public class Response
{
    public int TagNumber { get; set; }
    public string? TagName { get; set; }
    public string? Units { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public List<Item>? items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public DateTime? TimeStampValue { get; set; }
    public int ? Value { get; set; }
    public int? ConfidenceValue { get; set; }
    public int? SequenceValue { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my code:

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Response>>(responceConetent);
```

The `item` is null but other field can get the data correctly.

[image: Result After Running Code]

Can someone help me?

Comment: There's nothing special to lists. If you get null fields it's because either the data was missing or the mapping failed

Comment: Well, json has 4 arrays, but you have 1 array with 4 properties, you can not serialize it like this. But after serializing it as a proper model you can convert it as you want.

Comment: BTW there are no dates in your string. In JSON [dates should be in ISO-8601 format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3). Those localized strings would fail parsing in all countries in the world except one

Comment: There's no `items` attribute in your JSON. There's no array of `Item` objects at all, there are other arrays of raw values.

Comment: Your Json-object seem to use the ["Structure of Arrays"-pattern instead of "Array of structure"-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA) that you seem to expect. You can convert between the patterns, but you need to do so yourself, it will not be done by the serialization library.

Answer (score 3):

The class(es) you have don't match the object in the JSON.  It needs to match, unless you're writing a custom deserializer.

Update the class structure to match that JSON:

```
public class Response
{
    public int TagNumber { get; set; }
    public string? TagName { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public List<int> Value { get; set; }
    public List<int> Confidence { get; set; }
    public List<int> Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

---

Note that I'm not entirely confident the `DateTime` values will deserialize.  That could be up to culture settings perhaps.  At worst they may be strings:

```
public class Response
{
    public int TagNumber { get; set; }
    public string? TagName { get; set; }
    public List<string> TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public List<int> Value { get; set; }
    public List<int> Confidence { get; set; }
    public List<int> Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

And then you could convert the `List<string>` to a `List<DateTime>` in another model structure to use in your code, making the overall "deserialization" more of a two-step process.  Unless there's an easy way to get the deserializer to handle the format of those time stamps.  It's a separate issue that you may need to investigate, but at worst it just becomes a two-step process.